# Polygon and line input for point output (in R)

Tags: r, gis, spatial, spatstat

I'd like to create a a .shp file or data table of coordinates where the output point features are where line endpoints touch at a point on the polygon boundary and where lines cross polygon boundaries. No points are generated in the output where lines lie directly along polygon boundaries.

[image: See]

Can this be done in R?

[Like the intersect tool in Esri](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000.htm)?

I have both classes (in R)...

1. SpatialLines
2. SpatialPolygons

I simply can't seem to find a tool/package that does this...

(I am a beginner)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154689/how-to-find-the-coordinates-of-the-intersection-points-between-two-spatiallines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `spatstat` package, but you need to convert
from `SpatialLines` and `SpatialPolygons` to `psp` (planar segment
pattern) and `owin` (observation window -- a polygon in the plane) using
the `maptools` package.

Since you didn't provide example data I will first construct
SpatialPolygons and SpatialLines objects looking like your graphic:

```r
library(maptools)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.48-0.029       (nickname: 'Alternative Facts') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
A <- owin(c(1,3), c(2,5))
B <- owin(c(4,7), c(1,5))
p <- union.owin(A,B)
p <- as(p, "SpatialPolygons")
l <- psp(c(0.5, 0.5), c(2, 4), c(4, 6), c(2, 4), window = owin(c(0,7), c(0,5)))
l <- as(l, "SpatialLines")
plot(p)
plot(l, col = "green", add = TRUE, lwd = 3)
```

[image]

Now to do what you ask you convert the edges of the polygon to a `psp`
and find where the lines cross these edges (returned as a planar point
pattern `ppp`):

```r
l <- as(l, "psp")
p <- as(p, "owin")
e <- edges(p)
x <- crossing.psp(l, e)
x
#> Planar point pattern: 4 points
#> window: rectangle = [1, 6] x [2, 4] units
```

Adding the points to the plots shows what we found:

```r
plot(p, main = "")
plot(l, col = "green", add = TRUE, lwd = 3)
plot(x, add = TRUE, col = "red", pch = 20, cex = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: This works a treat and a great explanation! Thank you so much!